# How to use health check configurations in .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, health-check

In my .Net 5 API, I'm using end point for health check as follows,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc", new HealthCheckOptions { Predicate = _ => false });
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/rc");
    });
}
```

But I have some API, which is based on `netcoreapp2.1`. How can I use the above health configuration in 2.1

Comment: What is wrong with using the code you posted here?

Comment: @DavidG I removed that code part, I added that because  `HealthCheckOptions` using it

Comment: While implementing on `netcoreapp2.1` you should add `services.AddHealthChecks()` inside the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` and then add `app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz")` within the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method. For details implementation, you could [`refer to the official document here`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/#how-to-use-it).

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I think its for a `Core 2.2.0`. I tried as mentioned there, but its not working

Comment: Yes I know as you might know `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` was introduced from `asp.net core 2.2.0` as [`you can have a look here`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/2.2.0-preview1-35029#versions-body-tab) and there is no version for `2.1.0`. so that you cannot implement this on your version even though the `2.2.0` [`has been deprecated`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/2.2.0-preview1-35029)